# NSURLConnection different result when get error

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm using `-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest...]` to connect to a server, 
and when the server side fails it will respond with an error 400 with a message in the body.
When there is no error, I can get response data in didReceiveData. But when the server returns an error 400, I do not receive any error message in didReceiveData.

However if I use `-[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest...]` to do the same request 
I do get error data from `sendSynchronousRequest`'s return value.

I want to get the error message from didReceiveData, but I dont know why I cannot get it.
What is different between the do, can someone help me?

This way I can get the error message:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devapi.xxx.com/v1/debug/error"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                          timeoutInterval:240] autorelease];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];


NSLog(@"STATUS:%d", [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode]);
NSLog(@"ERROR:%@", error);
```

This way I cannot get it:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devapi.xxx.com/v1/debug/error"]
                                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                         timeoutInterval:240] autorelease];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
urlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"statusCode:%d",((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[receivedData appendData:data];
NSLog(@"DATA:%@",[NSString stringWithCString:[receivedData bytes] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
}
```

Comment: Do successful (non-400) responses call `didReceiveData`? Is `didFailWithError` ever called?

Comment: Can you please show your log output for Status, data and error ?

Comment: His problem is that when the HTTP code is not 200, he cannot always read the "content" part of the response from the server. It's a problem because that's where it is written which kind of application-error it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found what happen it is,
When I get a error status code in didReceiveResponse,
I immediately try to get data and cancel connection,
But it is wrong, 
Because didReceiveData still in receive after didReceiveResponse.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use this delegate method for handling such errors.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
      NSLog(@" Failed with error---%@",error);
}
```